# Uber native login flagging error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uber-api

I am currently running the example codes provided by Uber SDK (Objective C version).

I encounter a problem when I clicked on the Native Login and Ride Request Widget Button provided by the Objective C example.

After setting up the app in Uber and also copied the Client ID to the info.plist, I counter the error below:

When I click at the Ride Request Widget Button, the app will load a new view with the "Ride there with Uber" button. After clicking the "Ride there with Uber" button, the example app will flag a UIAlert with a message of "There seems to be a problem connecting to Uber. Please go back to AppName and try again". What could be the problem?

Btw, I fill in the redirect URL as "myapp://oauth/callback" on both the dashboard and the app info.plist.

Anything I miss out during the setup of this example?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share your source code? Are you using the [full Widget](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/ride-request-widget) or just the [Button](https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk/#ride-request-button)?

Comment: @Calvin I am also facing same issue, did u get any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the URL Scheme in Targets > Info is set to something like sampleApp, and not sampleApp://uberSSO. This solved my problem.

For reference, here is the snippet from the Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>MySampleAppName</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>sampleApp</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```